# Parse Server - Cannot enable verbose and cloud logLevel modes

Tags: node.js, parse-platform

I am using heroku running Parse server 4.4.0. I am unable to enable verbose mode.

logLevel also does not work.

I check many posts that say set VERBOSE=1 but this does not work. what are the option options?

here is my index.js

```
var express = require('express');
var cors = require('cors');
var ParseServer = require('parse-server').ParseServer;
var path = require('path');

var databaseUri = process.env.DATABASE_URI || process.env.MONGODB_URI;

var api = new ParseServer({
  databaseURI: databaseUri,
  cloud: process.env.CLOUD_CODE_MAIN || __dirname + '/cloud/main.js',
  appId: process.env.APP_ID,
  masterKey: process.env.MASTER_KEY, 
  serverURL: process.env.SERVER_URL ,  
  javascriptKey: process.env.JAVASCRIPT_KEY,
  restAPIKey: process.env.REST_API_KEY,
  clientKey: process.env.CLIENT_KEY,
  verbose:process.env.VERBOSE,
  logLevel: process.env.LOG_LEVEL // VERBOSE, INFO, ERROR, NONE, defaults to INFO
});
var app = express();
app.use(cors()); 

// Serve static assets from the /public folder
app.use('/public', express.static(path.join(__dirname, '/public')));

// Serve the Parse API on the /parse URL prefix
var mountPath = process.env.PARSE_MOUNT || '/parse';
app.use(mountPath, api);

// Parse Server plays nicely with the rest of your web routes
app.get('/', function(req, res) {
  res.status(200).send('Make sure to star the parse-server repo on GitHub!');
});

var port = process.env.PORT || 1337;
var httpServer = require('http').createServer(app);
httpServer.listen(port, function() {
    console.log('parse-server-example running on port ' + port + '.');
});
```

Comment: Try with `verbose:!!process.env.VERBOSE`

Comment: No it didn't work.

Comment: can you please try just with `verbose: true,` to make sure? this is a boolean var.

Comment: This also didn't work.

Comment: Why do you say it is not working? Where are you checking the logs?

Comment: I have installed PaperTrail in Heroku and also doesn’t work in logs in Heroku when I go to view logs.

Comment: I deleted env variable LOG_LEVEL and now I see verbose logs !! What could be the correlation?

Comment: Yes. It may be related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else comes looking for this issue then solution is to delete environment variable LOG_LEVEL.

I don't know why this happens but using logLevel variable does not work it seems May be Parse developers can look at it.

Happy if somebody points out any other solution if there is one.